# Second-Generation Managed Package with Package.xml

Tags: managed-package, package.xml, second-generation-packaging

i would like to ask if there is a way to further restrict data which gets into package based on package.xml for example like when retrieving metadata... Basically what I need is to have a git repository of metadata and a package.xml to narrov metadata which gets into package.

Comment: Personally, I would separate out the code into two or more repositories.

Comment: No, you can't use package.xml as a filter for your packages. This question appears to be an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Other potential solutions might be to specify org-dependent packaging or skipping validation on package upload.